# Laravel-Mix adds a bunch of code in js file

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

There's probably a simple solution for this and I cannot figure it out. I have a simple script file I was trying to compile with Laravel mix. When I run `npm run dev`, it compiles and adds a ton of code that I have no idea where. I have a simple function to try to get it to fire:

```
function hello(){
    console.log('hi');
}
```

The code that gets compiled is:

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  // The module cache
/******/  var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/  // The require function
/******/  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/   // Check if module is in cache
/******/   if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/   }
/******/   // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/   var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/    i: moduleId,
/******/    l: false,
/******/    exports: {}
/******/   };
/******/
/******/   // Execute the module function
/******/   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/   // Flag the module as loaded
/******/   module.l = true;
/******/
/******/   // Return the exports of the module
/******/   return module.exports;
/******/  }
/******/
/******/
/******/  // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/  __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/  // expose the module cache
/******/  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/  // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/  __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/   if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/     configurable: false,
/******/     enumerable: true,
/******/     get: getter
/******/    });
/******/   }
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/  __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/   var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/    function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/    function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/   __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/   return getter;
/******/  };
/******/
/******/  // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/  __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/  // __webpack_public_path__
/******/  __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/  // Load entry module and return exports
/******/  return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__(1);
module.exports = __webpack_require__(2);


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

/**
 * This takes the AJAX error response and returns it in a readable format.
 */
function hello() {
  console.log('hi');
}

/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

The function hello() is in there, but cannot be called. It says it's not defined. Here's my webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/page/page.js', 'public/js/')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I found one article on a laracast about this, but it was a weird solution for them. Help?

**UPDATE**
For some odd reason, instead of .js, .scripts was needed in the webpack.mix.js file. I don't know why that worked only in this project.

Comment: If you want plain Javascript to be compiled and minified use `.scripts(input, output)` rather than `.js(..)`.

Comment: I don't know why, that works. I have mix using .js in another and it's just fine. For some odd reason, this one wanted scripts. Thanks for that!

Comment: I am sure someone else can explain it a bit better but from the sounds of it `.js` will turn all the input files into modules so they can be access between each other but not from anything outside the bundle (ie output file). Whereas `.scripts` will output as standard js but minified.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `hello` function is encapsulated within the webpack module system, and it might not be accessible in the global scope. To make it globally accessible, you can explicitly assign it to the window object.

Try modifying your `page.js` file like this:

```
    window.hello = function () {
         console.log('hi');
    };
```

By attaching `hello` to the `window` object, it becomes a global function and should be accessible from anywhere in your application.

After making this change, run `npm run dev` again to recompile your assets and check if the `hello` function is now accessible in the global scope.

Comment: It is not recommended to add properties directly to window object as it could pollute the window object. It's better to create a new file js, write the necessary functions and add it in the listing of mix config